# How to set model property With ViewBag value?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, asp.net-mvc-4

I want set value into ViewBag, like bellow

```
 public ActionResult Register(Guid accountId)
 {
            ViewBag.AccountId = accountId;

            return View("Register", "Account");
  }
```

Now within **Register** View, can I set, like bellow

```
 @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.AccountId, new { id = "hdaccountid", value = ViewBag.AccountId })
```

I want to update model property with ViewBag value. So when I want to update model within controller, so model property contains the proper value.

I don't want use to ModelView. Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood...

You can not use `HiddenFor` if you dont pass model to view.

View

```
@Html.Hidden("accountId",  ViewBag.AccountId )
@Html.Hidden("id",  "hdaccountid" )
```

Controller

```
// pass parameter to view
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Register(Guid accountId)
{
    ViewBag.AccountId = accountId;

    return View();
    //return View("Register", "Account");
}

// post parameter from view
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Register(Guid accountId, string id)
{
    // Get model from DB and change it
    // model.accountId = accountId;
    ...
}
```

Comment: If I have `MoveToRegister(Guid accountId)`  set accountid within a view as hidden as u described, then another one `Register(UserModel Model)` From this Update database ?

Comment: If you want get model from view, you should pass model to view.

Comment: @ AliRıza Adıyahşi: If I want, hidden value into controller then how can I get that. Actually I have two ActionResult--> from one it pass accountid to a view. Then entry some value --> Submit a form --> call another action result and save data into db, including hidden field value.